# Поле класса имеет возвращаемый тип, что и сам класс

Tags: c#, .net, классы

[image: Создание класса с полями. Одно из полей имеет возвращаемый тип, что и класс]

Допустим создан класс Person, у которого есть какие-то поля. И одно из полей имеет тип класса, в который он и входит. Как руководствоваться данным полем. Какие значение оно может принимать и вообще в каких случаях данная реализация нужна?

Comment: Это обычное поле класса, с ним можно делать все, что можно делать с полем класса. Подробное используется во многих случаях, например, при реализации связанного списка.

Comment: а какие значение данное поле может принимать?

Comment: Я бы к ответу ещё добавил, что не стоит такое поле (или свойство) инициализировать сразу же, то есть в теле класса писать `Person Friend1 = new Person();` (или в конструкторе), иначе получишь переполнение стека. Такой код просто попадет в бесконечную рекурсию и вылетит с ошибкой. Это конечно очевидная вещь, но на всякий случай)

Comment: спасибо за вклад)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас здесь не поля, а [свойства](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php). Важно разбираться. Джефри Рихтер ("CLR via C#"): `Можно считать свойства «умными» полями, то есть полями с дополнительной логикой. <...> Cвойства выглядят как поля, на самом деле являясь методами.`Важно разбираться.

Во-вторых, создавать поле/свойство Person.person не рекомендую, так как желательно, чтобы из названия поля можно было понять для чего оно предназначено.

Поле/свойство определенного типа может принимать только значения этого типа, в данном случае Person.

Ну и для чего это нужно, например:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int Age{get; set;}
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public Person Friend1{get; set;}  // Это значит, что Friend1 и Friend2 являются объектами типа Person, 
        public Person Friend2{get; set;}  //  и у них также есть свойства  Age, Name, Friend1, Friend2 (не обязательно заполненные)
    }        

    static void Main()
{
    Person person1 = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();
    Person person3 = new Person(); //Создали 3 человек

    person1.Name = "Alex";        
    person1.Age = 12;
    person1.Friend1 = person2;
    person1.Friend2 = person3; // person1 содержит 2 ссылки на своих друзей - person2 и person3

    person2.Name = "Dan";
    person2.Age = 13;
    // person2.Friend1="Alex";  - выдаст исключение, потому что Friend1 должно быть типом Person
    person2.Friend1 = person1; // person2 дружит только с person1, второго друга нет

    person3.Name = "Bill";    // у person3 вообще нет друзей
    person3.Age = 14;
}
```

Пример **очень** утрированный, но суть думаю ясна.

Comment: спасибо огромное. Теперь стало ясно.

Comment: `нечто среднее между полем и методом` - не стоит так писать. Это один или два метода (геттер или сеттер могут отсутствовать), вызов которых **синтаксически похож** на чтение и запись значений поля или переменной. Самолет тоже похож на птицу, но было бы странно прочитать фразу что самолет - нечто среднее между машиной и птицей.

Comment: @rdorn: Вы будете смеяться, но это один, два или **три** метода) На уровне `IL` для свойства можно задать методы под `.get`, `.set` и `.other`. То есть действие, которое будет исполнено и не при считывании, и не при установке значения ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov не буду смеяться. C# не покрывает возможностей IL, так что в контексте конкретного языка - все таки один или два. Ни один высокоуровневый язык не покрывает всех низкоуровневых возможностей своей платформы, неизбежная цена за комфорт и скорость разработки.

Comment: @rdorn: таки да) В `IL` столько всего интересного обнаружилось) В принципе, если написать библиотеку на чистом IL и подключить ее к программе, написанной на `C#`, мы все же можем получить свойство, объединяющее 3 метода)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Но реально использовать сможем только два, так что не прокатит =)

Comment: @rdorn Возможно, неправильно выразился, но для базового понимания новичку мое определение вполне подойдет. Вот как определяет свойства Джефри Рихтер ("CLR via C#"):  `Можно считать свойства «умными» полями, то есть полями с дополнительной логикой.`

Comment: Рихтер, перед тем как дать "упрощенное" определение, показывает как они устроены внутри и зачем это вообще понадобилось. Я не призываю разворачивать ответ до лекции о свойствах, ссылки вполне достаточно, но подправить формулировку все же стоит, хотя бы процитировав Рихтера. Мне нравится ваш ответ, плюсик поставил сразу, но почему бы не сделать его чуточку лучше.

Comment: ну еще одна цитата оттуда же, чуть далее по тексту `... свойства выглядят как поля, на самом деле являясь методами. ...`

Comment: @rdorn исправил, спасибо за вклад :)